# Map's key-value relationship in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm using Map in TypeScript and I was thinking whether it's possible to make the compiler understand what the value is based on the key.

Example:

```js
const myMap = new Map<Type, Type[]>([
    [1, [1, 2, 3, 4]],
    ["foo", ["apple", "grape", "banana"]],
    [true, [true, false, true]],
]);
```

If I did this, I'd expect TypeScript to know that if I'm trying to a value by a boolean key, the value is an array of booleans (or `undefined`).

```js
myMap.get(false); // boolean[] | undefined
```

Can it even be done in TypeScript?

Comment: How safely? You could _declaration merge_ e.g. `interface Map<K, V> { get<T>(value: T): T[] | undefined; }`, but that wouldn't prevent you putting the wrong thing _into_ the map. You're probably better off composing a map into a structure that enforces (at compile _and run_ time) what you want.

Comment: There's no relationship between the types of keys and values in `Map`. You can certainly do this, but you'd have to do it with your own map-like object (which you could implement with a `Map` under the covers; it can't be a subclass because it doesn't have the same interface, but it can certainly be map-like). `set` would be like `set<T>(key: T, value: T[]) { this.#map.set(key, value); }` and `get` would be `get<T>(key: T): T[] | undefined { return this.#map.get(key); }`. I'm not sure how you'd type the iterable for the constructor, or `entries`, so you might not do them...

Comment: @RoboRobok - Obviously he does. Hence "[declaration merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#handbook-content)." (And frankly that comment comes across quite rudely.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can construct such a type
This is basically an intersection of a map of each type

```
const MyMap = Map as new (
  entries?: (
    | [number, number[]]
    | [string, string[]]
    | [boolean, boolean[]]
  )[]
) => Map<number, number[]> & Map<string, string[]> & Map<boolean, boolean[]>

const myMap = new MyMap([
  [1, [1, 2, 3, 4]],
  ["foo", ["apple", "grape", "banana"]],
  [true, [true, false, true]],
]);

let b = myMap.get(false); // boolean[] | undefined
//  ^?
```

Comment: Interesting! (`entries` should be `Iterable` rather than specifically an array: https://tsplay.dev/NBYepw). Can you generalize that? Some kind of create function?

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the possible types. I know it can be done this way. I want it to take any possible type, including class instances.

Comment: @RoboRobok I made this example specifically to show this is technically possible. If you need an actual implementation please add test cases. The problem here is that your types may get pretty random - what if you want `number->string & string->number`? What if you want `enum->enum`? So I can't just apply `Each<Wide<T>, T=>[T, T[]]>`. Please write out all cases to be covered, expect those you missed to not be covered.

Answer (score 0):

I've generalized another my answer to accept any generic key-value pair

With it you may make a map from anything to anything
(make sure that keys don't overlap tho)

```
type KeyValueMapBase<T extends readonly (readonly [any, any])[]> =
  | T extends [readonly [infer K, infer V], ...infer L extends readonly (readonly [any, any])[]]
  ? Map<K, V> & KeyValueMapBase<L>
  : unknown

type KeyValueMapT<T extends readonly (readonly [any, any])[]> =
  | {
    [K in keyof Map<any, any>]:
    | K extends typeof Symbol.iterator ? () => IterableIterator<T[number]>
    : K extends keyof KeyValueMapBase<T> ? KeyValueMapBase<T>[K]
    : Map<any, any>[K]
  }

interface KeyValueMap<T extends readonly (readonly [any, any])[]> extends KeyValueMapT<T> { }

type KeyValueMapConstructor = new <T extends readonly (readonly [any, any])[]>(entries?: readonly [...T]) => KeyValueMap<T>

const KVMap = Map as KeyValueMapConstructor;

let map = new KVMap([
  // ^?
  [1, [1, 2, 3, 4]] as const,
  ["foo", ["apple", "grape", "banana"]],
  [true, [true, false, true]],
]);


let map1 = new KVMap([
  // ^?
  [1, [1, 2, 3, 4]] as const,
  ["foo", ["apple", "grape", "banana"]],
  [true, [true, false, true]],
] as const);

let v = map1.get('foo')
//  ^?

let x = [...map1]
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no iterable constructor here as I was lazy to UnionToTuple here. Also doesn't work with infinite arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be less type-calcus, but requires explicit type arguments...

```
type HelperA<T extends readonly unknown[], Output extends unknown[] = []> =
    T extends [infer H, ...infer HS] ? HelperA<HS, [...Output, [H, H[]]]> : Output[number];

type Arg = HelperA<[number, string, boolean]>;
//   ^?

type HelperB<T extends readonly unknown[], Output extends unknown = unknown> =
    T extends [infer H, ...infer HS] ? HelperB<HS, Output & Map<H, H[]>> : Output;

type Ret = HelperB<[number, string, boolean]>;
//   ^?

const MyMap = Map as new <T extends readonly unknown[]>(
  entries?: (HelperA<T>)[]
) => HelperB<T>;

const myMap = new MyMap<[number, string, boolean]>([
  [1, [1, 2, 3, 4]],
  ["foo", ["apple", "grape", "banana"]],
  [true, [true, false, true]],
]);

let b = myMap.get(false); // boolean[] | undefined
//  ^?
```